# Why is the input not getting printed?

Tags: javascript, html, button

HTML:

```
<p id="p1">Player1</p>

<input type="text" placeholder="hello" id="firstname">

<button id="clickBtn" type="button">Click</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
let clickBtn = document.getElementById('clickBtn');
let firstname = document.getElementById('firstname');
let p1 = document.getElementById('p1');
clickBtn.onclick = function () { p1.innerText = firstname.value; console.log(firstname.value); }
```

In this it is showing uncaught error in console and it seems there is some error in the button.
I can't see any thing getting printed on console or the screen after entering in the input.

I expected the text which I entered gets printed.

Comment: Welcome! What’s the error you get?

Comment: It shows in the console as uncaught error in the sixth line of script ,can't read onclick or addEventListener

Comment: There is no error. But, the logic of the code is incorrect. You are setting nothing (p1.innerText) to the textbox, so the printed value is nothing.

Comment: @VidhiGoyal: *"it is showing uncaught error in console [...] it seems there is some error [...] can't read onclick or addEventListener"* - What is the **exact error** and what **exact code** produces that error?  Don't ignore the error, it's trying to tell you what the problem is.

Comment: It's showing cannot set properties of null(setting 'onclick') at script.js:4:18  anonympus@script.js:4.                  
 I understood that error is in that line but what is that error I can't understand..

Comment: @VidhiGoyal: Then `clickBtn` is `null`, which means the element is not found when that line of code executes.  The linked duplicate contains more information.

Comment: Thanks, I understood the error was in the order I used in the code

Answer (score 0):

Your are reasigning the `firstname.value` to `p1.innerText`, which have none text.

Try the code below:

```
let clickBtn = document.getElementById('clickBtn');
let firstname = document.getElementById('firstname');
let p1 = document.getElementById('p1');

clickBtn.onclick = function () {
  p1.innerText = firstname.value;
  console.log(firstname.value);
}
```

```
<p id="p1"></p>

<input type="text" placeholder="hello" id="firstname">

<button id="clickBtn" type="button">Click</button>
```

Comment: It's not working in mine

Comment: @VidhiGoyal Please see if there's error at these specific code lines in console and provide the message.

Comment: I got to know from the comments section that I had some error in my order so the error occurred, now the problem I was facing is resolved .But thankyou for answering